# How to cycle through ConEmu windows

Tags: conemu

ConEmu provides a command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> which brings up the console from anywhere. I usually have 2 or more ConEmu windows open and it would just be very nice if I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to cycle through the different windows. Is there a way to do that or configure that?

Comment: Nope. Global hotkey has effect over one (first) instance only. You may try Win+digit if ConEmu is pinned to first 10 slots of TaskBar

Comment: Oh bummer, your alternative suggestion is not bad either, might try that. Thanks for the help anyway!